# XSLT to transform one XML file to another and display as HTML

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, asp.net-mvc, xslt

I have the following two xml files:

```
<questionnaire>
<questionnaireid>1</questionnaire>
<questionnairename>sample questionnaire</questionnairename>
<questions>
    <question qid="1" >
        <qid>1</qid>
        <questiondesc>Q1) Enter some free text</questiondesc>
        <typeid>2</typeid>
        <required>1</required>
        <parentquestion></parentquestion>
    </question>             
    <question qid="2" >
        <qid>2</qid>    
        <questiondesc>Q2) Select any of the choices</questiondesc>  
        <typeid>6</typeid>
        <required>1</required>
        <parentquestion></parentquestion>
        <choices>
            <choice>Choice1</choice>
            <choice>Choice2</choice>
            <choice>Choice3</choice>
        </choices>
    </question>
</questions>
```

```
<questionnaireresponse>
  <questionnaireid>1</questionnaire>
  <userid>1234</userid>
     <responses>
        <response qid="1">
          <answers>
            <answer>This is some text</answer>
          </answers>
        </response>
        <response qid="2">
          <answers>
             <answer>Choice 2</answer>
          </answers>
       </response>
    </responses>
 </questionnaireresponse>
```

How do you use xslt to add the response for this user to questionnare file and display as HTML form so in the above example the textbox will be populated with 'This is some text' and the dropdown will have 'Choice 2' selected?

Some example xslt implementing the above would be very helpful to get started. ideally I would like to do this in asp.net

Comment: So typeid=2 means the form control for the question is and edit box; and typeid=6 means use a pull-down? or does some-thing else decide the production of form controls?

Comment: If it's MVC, Why XSLT? why not razor?

Comment: You have forgotten to provide the exact wanted output -- if you don't know what the result should be, then this isn't a question at all.